# Checkbox1.checked returns false vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox

i am working with vb.net i have take html checkbox runat server and on link button click event i want to access this checkbox i have tried checkbox.checked but this always  returns false
 
on link button click

```
If ckice.Checked = True Then
    ckice.Value = "Yes"
Else
    ckice.Value = "No"
End If
```

Comment: Where are your html and PageLoad event code?

Comment: Tested it, when code is in Button_Click - it correctly detects true/false. Have you disabled viewstate?

Comment: <input type="checkbox" id="ckice" runat="server"  />

Comment: on page load i am doing nothing regarding this

Comment: What are you doing with ckice.Value??? Your setting the "Value" of a checkbox based on the check state of the same control???

Comment: i am passing this ckice value to DB.If checkbox is checked then Yes otherwise No. user.columnname=ckice.value

Answer (score 0):

Use code like this:

```
<div>
<input id="Check1"  type="checkbox" runat="server" checked="checked"/> 
        CheckBox1 &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span id="Span1" style="color:red" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="Button1" value="Enter"
           onserverclick="Button1_Click" runat="server"/>
</div>
```

On Back End:

```
Sub Button1_Click(ByVal Source As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If Check1.Checked = True Then
        Span1.InnerHtml = "Check1 is checked!"
        Check1.Value = "Yes"
    Else
        Span1.InnerHtml = "Check1 is not checked!"
        Check1.Value = "No"
    End If
End Sub
```